# Why can't a PC with 2 network cards be accessed by hostname?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, tcp

I set up PC with 2 network cards, connected to the same LAN.
I can connect to this PC (e.g. by remote desktop) only via IP addresses. Accessing by hostname does not work.

Why is this the case?

**UPDATE:**
Full environment

1. PC with 2 hardware network adapters.
2. On this PC installed VMWare Workstation. Created 3 VM's, networked by "bridged" network setting in VMWare.
3. In LAN all IP addresses given from DHCP.
4. Win2k8 on all hosts (both physical and virtual).
   **As result:**
5. PC has 2 IP addresses (e.g. 192.168.1.71 and 192.168.1.72). PC available in LAN by IP addresses, but not available by hostname.
6. VM's has own IP address on each (e.g. 192.168.1.73, *74, *75 etc). They are available from LAN by their ip's, BUT not by their hostnames.

*How can I access to PC and to VM's by hostname?*

Comment: are they on the same domain or workgroup?

Comment: Describing a problem just by saying it doesn't work isn't helpful.

Comment: Daniel - yes, all computers in same workgroup.

Comment: what about any firewalls?

Comment: Firewalls are enabled. But what difference on fw, if host is accessible via IP-address?

Comment: Now I tried with disabled firewall - no diff, PC isn't accessible by hostname, only by ip.

Comment: I have always edited my **hosts** file to map IP addresses. If you cannot fix your problem, this is a good work around.

Comment: What kind of network is your LAN set as, Home, Work or Public?

Comment: And do you have the "Computer Browser" service running on these PCs? It's a requirement to get NetBIOS name resolution going. (Your other option is to setup a DNS server)

Comment: I'm trying to enable this service on my vitrual or physical PC's. "Computer browser" starts, but then stops after 10-15 seconds, without any speak.

Comment: You should check your Event Viewer for any error messages. Without that service you can't rely on NetBIOS to do name handling, and you won't be able to connect using anything but IP-adresses. But like i said, you should be able to just add the DNS service to one of your 2008s.

Comment: Event viewer logs are empty. Only 2 messages: "The Computer Browser service entered the **running** state." and after 10 seconds "The Computer Browser service entered the **stopped** state." PS: This service was "Disabled" on my host initially (and also was disabled on VM's, on all hosts). Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would just be to add the entries in your hosts file.

Open, using administrator privileges - your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

This file should already contain a couple lines like:

```
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Then just add relevant entries:

```
192.168.0.1 myawesomerouter
192.168.0.10 somethingelse
192.168.0.100 ahundred.domain.org
192.168.2.40 mygooglecopy.google.com
```

You can also use this to "blackhole" some sites, for example if you never wanted to communicate with www.google.com you could add the line:

```
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

Comment: How do you add entries to the hosts file? Could you edit your answer to reflect this?

Comment: @caimz, I don't want to use this solution, because it need to update **hosts** on each computer in LAN. IMHO, it is not good solution.

Comment: Well it was just a suggestion, since somehow your netbios doesn't seem to be in order to do proper name resolution. Does this apply to all VMs and the host? Also, what kind of router/thingie do you have in front?

Comment: @cairnz Yes, this trouble applies to all VM's and host. LAN is connected to ADSL-modem with DHCP server inside it.

Comment: @cairnz, LAN is work.

Answer (score 0):

Hostname resolution is typically handled by your router. Your IP configuration probably has your router's IP address as the DNS server. If that's the case, then the router will resolve the hostname to the local IP address.  If you have your system set to use alternate DNS servers, like Google's 8.8.8.8, then hostname resolution may fail.

Comment: Yes, all my hosts (physical and VM's) obtained ip-addresses from DHCP. DHCP server works on adsl-modem.